# Filtering GMail messages in Google App Engine application

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, gmail

I would like to build an application in Google App Engine (Python) that would be fully connected to a single GMail account and then filter e-mails from this account (e.g. filter messages for a certain string and show it on the string). In the future I am also going to implement the option to send messages.

What is the most efficient way to do this (solution provided by Google if possible)?

Comment: There is no API for Gmail, and no way to be "fully connected" to a Gmail account. Additionally, App Engine doesn't allow you to connect via IMAP, so you're pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "fully connected"?

It's possible to set up a GMail filter to forward emails to a different address (say, the email address of your App Engine app). And an App Engine app an send emails (say, to a GMail address). The trick is to set up the GMail filter carefully to avoid loops.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution in my case. By "fully connected" I mean something like context.io app, i.e. allowing me to login with my Google Account and then do some operations on my e-mail messages (using API provided by Google if possible).

Is there some API for e-mails received at my @appspot.com address?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Api for Gmail in App Engine. The only thing you can do is forwarding messages to App Engine.
I have used fowarding for building auto responders.

But there is an excellent GMail Api in Google Apps Script with lots of functions. Apps scrips uses javascript. And ofcourse your apps script can communicate with App Engine.